# PHP & MySQL - display only prodcucts and related information from selected category - three tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, categories

here is my homework assignment and I'm currently stuck on part 5:
http://yorktown.cbe.wwu.edu/sandvig/mis314/assignments/Assignment06.aspx

This is what the result should be like (Select a category and it populates the div on the right with pertinent products):
http://yorktown.cbe.wwu.edu/sandvig/MIS314/Assignments/A06/CategoryItems.php?catID=1

This is the current state of my version:
https://yorktown.cbe.wwu.edu/students/192/roversg/A06/categoryitems.php?category=T-shirts

The three tables are here in PDF format:
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AqSyu9NNp2DFtZMQgnJuOWgwhVELsQ

---

I can't figure out how to call up every item in one selected category in the second $sql = "SELECT [...]" statement.
I get that I have to join the tables but how do I make it so that an echo statement brings up ItemIDs, etc. associated to a specific CatID, when CatName is specified?

Below I will post my .php as it is is right now.

**this first portion is working fine**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
        <title>Product Categories</title>
        <link href="/sandvig/mis314/assignments/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include 'databaseconnection.php';

        //connect to database
        $link = fConnectToDatabase();

        $category = $_GET['category'];
        ?>

        <div class="pageContainer">
            <div class="centerText">
                <h3>Product Category Count</h3>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class='equalColumnWraper'>
                <div class='leftColumn'>     
                    <div class="centerText">
                        <h3>Categories</h3>
                    </div>


                    <?php
                    //List records
                    $sql = "SELECT ab.ItemID, ab.CatID, CatName 
                        ,COUNT(CatName) as count
                        from geekproducts a, geekcategories b, geekproductcategories ab
                        WHERE b.CatID = ab.CatID AND a.ItemID = ab.ItemID
                        GROUP BY CatID"
                    ;

                    //$result is an array containing query results
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
                            or die('SQL syntax error: ' . mysqli_error($link));

// iterate through the retrieved records
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        //Field names are case sensitive and must match
                        //the case used in sql statement
                        echo "
        <a class='menuLink' href='?category={$row['CatName']}'>{$row['CatName']} ({$row['count']})</a>";
                    }
                    ?> 

                </div>
```

**below is my problem**

```
                    //List records
                    if (isset($category)) {
                        $sql = "SELECT ab.ItemID, ab.CatID, CatName, Name, Image, price

                        from geekproducts a, geekproductcategories ab, geekcategories b
                        WHERE b.CatName = '$category'
                        ";
                    } else {
                        $sql = "SELECT Name, Image, price
                FROM geekproducts, geekcategories 
                ORDER by Name";
                    }

                    //$result is an array containing query results
                    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
                            or die('SQL syntax error: ' . mysqli_error($link));

                    echo "<div class='itemCount'>We sell " . mysqli_num_rows($result) . " items in '$category'</div>";

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        //Field names are case sensitive and must match
                        //the case used in sql statement\
                         echo "                            
                            <div class='productItem'>
                            <img src='/sandvig/mis314/assignments/a06/images/m_{$row['Image']}'  class='productImage'>
                            <div class='productName'>{$row['Name']}</div>
                            <div class='productPrice'>Price: ${$row['price']}</div>
                            <div class='productDesc'> {$row['ShortDesc']}</div>
                            </div>
                            ";
                    }
                    ?>                    



                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>

                </body></html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-write or change your query to this:

```
SELECT gp.ItemID, gc.CatID, gc.CatName, gp.Name, gp.Image, gp.Price 
FROM geekproducts gp 
JOIN geekproductcategories gpc ON gpc.ItemID = gp.ItemID
JOIN geekcategories gc ON gc.CatID = gpc.CatID
WHERE gc.CatName = "{$category}"
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I had no idea you could do FROM and JOIN the way you did, nor how to call in variables like that.

In the end I had to correct your answer to lowercase price and then go into the echo statement and modify the price div line to <div class = 'productPrice'>Price: $" . $row['price'] . "</div>

Comment: I'm glad i could help and yeah, that's the most common way to use JOIN in queries.  However, i would advice you take more tutorials about SQL and SQL Injection. Prepared statement is the best way to avoid query injections. About the price, my bad, I didn't notice the uppercase.

Comment: It's okay bro, no problem